# How can I put a reference at the end of the page using LaTeX?

Tags: footnotes, moderncv

I know how to use cite and regard to literature etc. but in that case I want to do something else:

I want something like that:

```
 Page 1:
 bla bla bla





 bla bla
 Grade: 4.6[1]
 bla bla


 bla
 ___________________________________________
 [1]: According to Russian grading system with 1: "insufficient" and 5 "excellent"
 end of page;
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Is `\footnote{}` what you want?

Comment: I try to use it with the moderncv class and I want to use it inside a \cventry but it tells me: Use of \@xfootnote doesn't match its definition. \@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}

Comment: If you want this to work with `moderncv` then you should say that in the question, ideally with a basic document which includes `\documentclass{moderncv}`. I think `moderncv` has some issues with footnotes inside `\cventry` which may be a separate question to fix.

Comment: @J.Doe Welcome to TeX.SX! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small document that shows your problem. Just edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Does this issue really related to `biblatex` and `csquotes`? The tags seem a bit out of place.

Comment: you can try with lastpage.sty

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\footnote`-command.  As long, as you don't have your footnotes looking like the ones, you quoted ("[1|"), this should be fine to you

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some normal text, which is typeset by Mr. Drofnats, a happy small
computer.\footnote{See the \TeX-Book for more details about Mr. Drofnats}

\end{document}
```

Ending in the text and the footnote at the end of the page:

[image: Footnotemark in text]
[image: Footnote at the end of the page]

Answer (score 0):

You can use with the help of `lastpage.sty` like below

```
\pageref{FirstPage} ............. \pageref{LastPage}
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the question. I think OP is asking for footnotes, right?